# How can i draw NACA foils in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am working with latex editor in overleaf. I would like to know the process how can I draw NACA 4415 airfoil with .dat file. Can anyone provide me a sample code?

Comment: Hi Abir, I think you already wrote to us at Overleaf support. It looks like you tried to create an Overleaf project using http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/airfoil-profiles/ . Something is going wrong with that procedure right now, and I've asked our developers to look into it. In the meantime, you can download the example files from that page and upload them to a new project on Overleaf manually. Here's an example I just created: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gqcrkmhhtktn

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your example. I've used your example and was able to develop NREL's s822, s823 airfoils. But I'm facing problems developing NACA series airfoils. example- Every time I try to run the code with naca4412.dat file an error shows up saying " dimension too large". Any solution? Here is my work https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d4e9ea299f02a41a0051b88

Comment: Your naca4412.dat file has the first line `NACA 4412` which are not valid coordinates, you need to add a comment character, like the other .dat files in the example: `% NACA 4412`. The same problem causes errors in your other airfoils too, though those are drawn correctly because TikZ is interpreting those lines different: they are seen as text and dropped. But nobody besides Overleaf support staff can see your project, so it's better to ask these project-specific questions on our support channel. Or post your code here on TeX.SX as an MWE in the question, not relying on external links.

Comment: Hi Paul. I was able to solve my problem. Thanks for your support.